# What do modern British people think about the decolonization of India in 1947?

Tags: united-kingdom, india, history, public-opinion

Do British people think that PM Clement Attlee's decision to give independence to India was correct?

If so, why?   If not, why not?

Comment: FYI, a more generic poll:  https://yougov.co.uk/topics/international/articles-reports/2020/03/11/how-unique-are-british-attitudes-empire

Comment: I doubt there would be polls nowadays second guessing decisions made decades ago (and which can't be easily revisited). In any case, I don't see how it fits the time frame normally envisaged for contemporary politics here.